# Spring @Autowired not working - expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Java 14 with Spring Boot 2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.

I have a resource, within which I try to Autowire a `approvalRequestService`.

**ApprovalRequestResource.java**

```
@RestController
public class ApprovalRequestResource {

    @Autowired
    ApprovalRequestService approvalRequestService;
```

Which is an interface:

**ApprovalRequestService.java**

```
@Service
public interface ApprovalRequestService {

    List<ApprovalRequestDTO> getApprovalRequests(String token);
}
```

And has the following implementation:

**ApprovalRequestServiceImpl.java**

```
public class ApprovalRequestServiceImpl implements ApprovalRequestService {

    @Autowired
    ApprovalRequestDAO approvalRequestDAO;

    @Autowired
    CompanyContactService companyContactService;

    @Autowired
    JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Override
    public List<ApprovalRequestDTO> getApprovalRequests(String jwtToken) {
```

When I start Spring Boot, I get the following error:

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> Description:
>
> Field approvalRequestService in
> com.nexct.approvalservice.resources.ApprovalRequestResource required a
> bean of type
> 'com.nexct.approvalservice.service.ApprovalRequestService' that could
> not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'com.nexct.approvalservice.service.ApprovalRequestService' in your
> configuration.
>
> Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55876',
> transport: 'socket'
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

and

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'approvalRequestResource': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'approvalRequestService'; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'com.nexct.approvalservice.service.ApprovalRequestService' available:
> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
> Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

**Question**

How have I wired this incorrectly?

It appears that it does not like the following in ApprovalRequestResource.java:

```
@Autowired
ApprovalRequestService approvalRequestService;
```

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps an autoscan issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the @Service annotation the implementation not the interface

```
public interface ApprovalRequestService {

    List<ApprovalRequestDTO> getApprovalRequests(String token);
}

@Service
public class ApprovalRequestServiceImpl implements ApprovalRequestService {
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. When I try move the `@Service` annotation to the implementation, I get a compilation error in the implementation where I have `@Autowired    ApprovalRequestDAO approvalRequestDAO;` - `Could not autowire. No beans of 'ApprovalRequestDAO' type found. `

Comment: Does the `ApprovalRequestDAO` class need an annotation defining what it is?  I have tried adding `@Bean` to the `ApprovalRequestDAO`, but it gets the following error: `'@Bean' not applicable to type`

Comment: Hi Simon, I got it working, thank you. I need to annotate the implementations down the chain, i.e. by adding `@Repository` to the DAO. So your answer was correct, the `@Service` annotation needed to be on the implementation and not the interface.